# Creating an instance from another instance?

Tags: java, inner-classes

I'm so confused that how could it be written like this... It creates an instance from another instance

***st.new FirstLevel();***

```
    public class ShadowTest {

    public int x = 0;



    class FirstLevel {

        public int x = 1;

        void methodInFirstLevel(int x) {
            System.out.println("x = " + x);
            System.out.println("this.x = " + this.x);
            System.out.println("ShadowTest.this.x = " + ShadowTest.this.x);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        ShadowTest st = new ShadowTest();
        ShadowTest.FirstLevel fl = st.new FirstLevel();
        fl.methodInFirstLevel(23);

        ShadowTest.FirstLevel mali = st.new FirstLevel();           
    }
}
```

Comment: It creates an instance of an inner class.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @tgallei Cant I create the instance of FirstLevel class just by typing ShadowTest.FirstLevel fl = new FirstLevel();

Comment: Best way to figure it out is by trying

Answer (score 1):

Here, `FirstLevel` is a so-called **inner class** – that's because it is defined *inside* another class. Both relations (the 'outer' and the 'inner') are plain jane classes (and not interfaces, enums, or records). In this case, unless the inner class has the modifier `static` on it (and, in your code, it doesn't), then you get an **instance inner class**.

Such classes have a hidden field of the outer type associated with them. It is as if your `FirstLevel` class has this field:

```
private final ShadowTest outerInstance;
```

And each and every constructor of `ShadowTest` has a parameter for this field, but, it is hidden and a bit special.

Because this secret field exists, you can do things like invoke non-static methods from `ShadowTest` from within `FirstLevel`.

If you type `new FirstLevel()`, that just works... but only within non-static contexts inside `ShadowTest`. Anywhere else and the compiler will tell you that it doesn't know what instance of `ShadowTest` to pass along for that secret field. You can explicitly define which instance of `ShadowTest`. But not with `new FirstLevel(shadowTestInstance)`, but with the somewhat weird-looking syntax `shadowTestInstance.new FirstLevel()`. But, it's the same thing: A parameter being passed to a constructor.

I generally advise that you do not use instance inner classes unless you really know they are the best fit for the case; this hidden field tends to cause confusion and surprises. I'd go so far as to say that you should *never* have instance inner classes; if you must hold a reference to an instance of the outer class, make it explicit (add an actual field, and make an actual parameter in your constructor). That way you avoid the surprises and confusion, at least. In other words, mark your `FirstLevel` class as `static`. By making your outer reference explicit, the shadowing thing also goes away; now you just have `x` or `this.x` referring to the `x` field in `FirstLevel`, and `outerInstance.x` for the outer field:

```
static class FirstLevel {
    final ShadowTest shadow;
    int x;

    public FirstLevel(ShadowTest shadow) { this.shadow = shadow; }
}
```

Comment: that was explanatory thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

> As with instance methods and variables, an inner class is associated with an instance of its enclosing class and has direct access to that object's methods and fields. Also, because an inner class is associated with an instance, it cannot define any static members itself.[ref.javaOO_nested](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

As per java syntaxes, unless it's a private or static class you could initialize it in the following way

```
class OuterClass {
    ...
    class InnerClass {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then a sample initialisation can be done so:

```
OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass();
```

NOTE: I have referred the block to the oracle java docs. You can read more there

Comment: actualy I was studying from there the question was from oracle's doc thank you anyway :)